# Calculate the distance between two positions Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, getdistance

I'm building an application that tracks my running and walking but I'm getting some trouble with calculating the total distance.

Here is a part of my code where I'm getting the values of latitude and longitude and where I do my calculation of the distance.

```
public class SportsActicity {

protected Integer userId;
protected ArrayList<Position> route = new ArrayList<Position>();

public SportsActicity() {
    this.userId = 1;
}

public void track(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double altitude, float speed, long chron) {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Position currentPosition = new Position(currentDate, latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, chron);
    route.add(currentPosition);
    // Float velocidade =  (locat.getSpeed()*3600)/1000;
}

public double getTotalDistance() {
    double distance = 0;
    if(route.size() > 1) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < route.size() - 1; i++) {
            distance += test(route.get(i).latitude, route.get(i).longitude, route.get(i + 1).latitude, route.get(i + 1).longitude);
        }
    }
    return distance;
}

public Float test(Double lat1, Double lon1, Double lat2, Double lon2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371;
    double latDiff = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double lngDiff = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(latDiff /2) * Math.sin(latDiff /2) +           
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))* 
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))* Math.sin(lngDiff /2) * 
               Math.sin(lngDiff /2); 
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double distance = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Float(distance * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```

[image]

If I'm not moving, the total distance is always incrementing, around 10 (no idea if it is in meters), and the values I'm getting don't look correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Location's`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) static method [`distanceBetween`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) instead of your whole `test` method.

```
int[] results = new int[1];
Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, results);
int distance = results[0];
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssjIY.png I did what u said but I still get "stupid" values with the phone standing at the window. The values in distance was 0-8-11, and the coordinates are the 3 that u can see in the image. Regards

Answer (score 0):

From Google official repository [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/DistanceDemoActivity.java)

[SphericalUtil](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java)

[MathUtil](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/MathUtil.java)

**Usage**

```
 double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(new LatLng(9.000,10.00), new LatLng(9.000,11.00));
```

The above method will returns the distance between two LatLngs, in meters. **Or try this**

```
private String getDistance(LatLng my_latlong,LatLng frnd_latlong){
 Location l1=new Location("One");
 l1.setLatitude(my_latlong.latitude);
 l1.setLongitude(my_latlong.longitude);

 Location l2=new Location("Two");
 l2.setLatitude(frnd_latlong.latitude);
 l2.setLongitude(frnd_latlong.longitude);

 float distance=l1.distanceTo(l2);
 String dist=distance+" M";

  if(distance>1000.0f)
   {
     distance=distance/1000.0f;
     dist=distance+" KM";
   }

 return dist;

}
```

or you can give a look at [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

Comment: Thank you. I just forgot that GPS has an error. I just took the distance will I was driving and it hit right with the car's value (100m error).